# Single database call when passing in a list to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I get passed in an array of email addresses and for each email address, I need to return numTotal and numActive from members related to that email address.

Traditionally, I would query from the member table and filter where the member's email address exists in the passed in email array. However, this would only return me the list of email address with counts for the emails that exist in the member table. Instead, I need a record for each email address provided regardless if a member has the email address.

My solution is to loop over the email array and then do a subquery. This works, and I'm able to get what I need, but when I profile the calls, I see that EF is running a separate query for each email address/subquery.

```
var result = (from email in emailAddresses
              select new EmailAddressStats {
                 Total = membersQueryable.Any(m => m.Email == email),
                 Active = membersQueryable.Any(m => m.Email == email && m.IsActive)
              }).ToList();
```

So if I pass in 3 email addresses, I see 6 separate queries (3 email addresses * 2 subqueries).

I've tried making the array queryable using `.AsQueryable()`, but I'm still getting the same result.

Ideally I would like EF to generate something like:

```
SELECT ([totalSubquery]) AS Total,
       ([activeSubquery]) AS Active
FROM ????
WHERE EXISTS ('email1@domain.com', 'email2@domain.com', 'email3@domain.com' )
```

NOTE: I am using Entity Framework 4.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but couldn't you use `JOIN` for that? `RIGHT JOIN` I suppouse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have EF4 installed, but you should be able to something like this to only perform a single query.

```
List<EmailAddressStats> GetEmailAddressStats(string[] emailAddresses)
{
    var returnList = emailAddresses.Select(e => new EmailAddressStats { Email = e })
                                   .ToList();

    // I don't know what your context is actually called so I'm just calling it MemberDatabaseContext)
    using (var dbContext = new MemberDatabaseContext())
    {
        // Query the database once with a single query to get all of the relevant members
        var membersWithEmailAddress = dbContext.Members.Where(m => emailAddresses.Contains(m.Email))
                                                       .Select(m => new { Email = m.Email, IsActive = m.IsActive })
                                                       .ToList();

        // Update the email stats by analyzing the member info in memory
        foreach (var emailStat in returnList)
        {
            emailStat.Total = membersWithEmailAddress.Count(m => m.Email == emailStat.Email);
            emailStat.Active = membersWithEmailAddress.Count(m => m.Email == emailStat.Email && m.isActive);
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

(sorry that this is in Fluent syntax instead of the Query Expression syntax, but I only know how to do this in Fluent syntax)

Comment: That will only include members whose email address is in the passed in list. I need to have a record for each email address pass in, regardless if anyone has it or not, which is why I am looking through the list of emails instead of the filtered list of members.

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET I updated my answer after reading your comment and re-reading your question more carefully. Now it should only perform one database query and then do the "join" operation in memory. If this still does not answer your question can you please share a little more code surrounding the database call so that I can get a clearer picture of what you are trying to do?